# Comparing pixel colors in a selected region

Tags: android, android-canvas

```
canvas.drawCircle((float)(myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance/2.0), myMidPoint.y, (float)30.0, myPaint);

canvas.drawCircle((float)(myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance/2.0), myMidPoint.y, (float)30.0, myPaint);
```

The image shows the eyes detected using canvas. How to get the pixel colors in the circled region so that I can compare it with any preset values and tell whether eye is open or not?

See the image in [link](https://imgur.com/Z6QusUC).

Comment: i couldn't add the image as i have no 10 reputation

Comment: Then post a link to imgur or the equivalent

Comment: thanks..i did uploading in imgur..but i hav no account..still i hope the image will be accessible...http://imgur.com/Z6QusUC

Comment: @GabeSechan thank u once again for helping me..