# Android Image processing to search a pattern

Tags: image, image-processing

I am working with an android application for capturing an image and processing. My requirement is to scan the captured image for two thick lines and its colour on a white surface. I need to know how it is possible to do in android.

captured image is like this

[image]
Thanks for any help

Comment: You can lock the image data and process (scan) each pixel by iterating through lines and columns and check for the color of the current pixel. Actually you only need to do that in one line and remember the X (column) coordinates where you found the lines. [That might](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825978/detecting-black-pixel-in-an-image) be a good example.

Comment: In my requirement, There will be a red line which can be light to dark. I need to calculate a percentage value according to the intensity of the color. Is there are any way to find out this from the pixel?

Comment: No matter what color the line has, it won't be white. Therefore you can easily find the line by scanning the pixels. Once you found a pixel you can read its RGB values or transform it to HSV color space. Then you will have the saturation value as well.